# Error when trying to install grammar-check module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, module

I'm attempting to install [this pip module](https://pypi.org/project/grammar-check/) here, however whenever inputting `pip3 install grammar-check` or `pip3 install grammar-check==1.3.1` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement grammar-check (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for grammar-check
```

I'm currently running both the latest version of python and latest version of pip, so I'm not quite sure what the issue may be. Is the module too outdated? I haven't been able to find another similar module if so.

I haven't had this issue when installing other modules, such as [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/), which was installed using the method listed above.

Answer (score 1):

[`grammar-check`](https://pypi.org/project/grammar-check/#description) only has [wheels  for Python 2](https://pypi.org/project/grammar-check/#files), and no uploaded source distributions. Since there's no distribution files that are compatible with Python 3, pip reports the error that you're seeing.

You won't be able to directly install that distribution from PyPI under Python 3. However, looking at the [GitHub repo linked in the project's description](https://github.com/myint/language-check), there are manual steps for installing it in Python 3. Alternatively, you could try downloading a Python 2 wheel from PyPI and manually tweaking it to make it Python 3 compatible.